# How to override minicart content.html?

Tags: magento2, template, overrides, mini-cart, magento2.2.2

How can I override the following file for Magento-2.2.2

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html
```

Is there something different between `.html` and `.phtml` ??
As I have no problem with `.phtml` files overriding.

This is what I have done to override:

1. Copy the content from:
   `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html`
2. Paste the content and make little change in here:
   `app/design/frontend/VendorName/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html`
3. Perform all these:
   `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
   `php bin/magento -f setup:static-content:deploy`
   `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
   `php bin/magento cache:flush`
4. Browser's cache is also cleared!

After doing  all the things, no change in frontend.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: you can not change the web template knockout file directly for this you have to use the plugins or custom module for this.

Comment: May be your cache is not clear properly.Please delete file  from `var/view_proceeded,var/cache,var/page_cache`.

Comment: also delete all  files from pub/static but don't delete   `pub/static/.htaccess`

Comment: Clearing the var/page_cache solved my issue